# mostrar descripción de producto php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

tengo la siguientes líneas de código, la idea es que al tocar el producto que se muestra en pantalla te lleve a su pagina de descripción, el problema que tengo es que carga su pagina, pero en dicha url no me sale el id del producto, por ende me carga la pagina con errores de sql que no fue encontrado el producto y su variables.

Se que el error se encuentra en la linea

```
<a href="Products.php?nik=">
```

El punto es que no logro hacer que envié el id del producto seleccionado

Index con lista de productos

```
<div class="row">
                            
                        <?php foreach($productos as $producto ){ ?>
                            <!-- product -->
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
                                <div class="product">
                                 
                                        
                                    <div class="product-img">
                                      <img src="ADM/img/<?php echo $producto->url_image?>" alt="...">
                                        <div class="product-label">
                                    
                                            <span class="new">NUEVO</span>
                                        
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="product-body">
                                    <a href="Products.php?nik=">
                                        <p class="product-category"><?php echo $producto->categoria?></p>
                                        <h3 class="product-name"><?php echo $producto->descripcion?></h3>
                                        <h4 class="product-price">COD: <?php echo $producto->id ?></h4>
                                        <div class="product-btns">
                                        <!--
                                        
                                        <button onclick="window.location.href='Categorias/Accesorios/Catracas'" class="quick-view"><i class="fa <fa-e>         </fa-e>ye"></i><span class="tooltipp">Ir a la categoria</span></button>
                                        
                                        -->
                                        </div>
                                        </a>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    <div class="add-to-cart">
                                    <!--
                                        <button class="add-to-cart-btn"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>VER</button>
                                    -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /product -->
                        <?php } ?>
                       
                            

                            <div class="clearfix visible-sm visible-xs"></div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /STORE -->
```

Pagina que muestra el producto

```
<?php
        include("../BD/conexion.php");
        ?>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
        <br>
            <h2>Datos del producto</h2>
            <hr />
            
            <?php
            // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
            $nik = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,(strip_tags($_GET["nik"],ENT_QUOTES)));
            
            $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE id='$nik'");
            if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 0){
                //header("Location: index.php");
            }else{
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
            }
            ?>
                <div class="detalles">  
                    <div class="">
                    <div class=""><span>Codigo: </span><?php echo $row['categoria'];?></div>
                    <div class=""><span>Categoria:</span> <?php echo $row['categoria']; ?></div>
                    <div class=""><span>Descripcion:</span> <?php echo $row['descripcion'];?></div>
                    </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
                        
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No le estás pasando ningún valor en el enlace:

```
<a href="Products.php?nik=">
```

Debes ponerlo así:

```
<a href="Products.php?nik=<?php echo $producto->id ?>">
```

Comment: Es que lo deje en blanco porque con lo que habia probado me tira lo escrito ejemplo  /Products.php?nik=id por eso era la pregunta, asi como me lo dices tu me funciono

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro que te haya servido :-)  Recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta que te ha ayudado más a solucionar tu problema.  Saludos!